# Python Scraping website_tab

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to transform scraping Hedgefollow website in dataframe.
This is the code:
can you help me in this transformation?

```
import selenium.webdriver
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

url = ''
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.binary_location = r'C:/Local/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe'
driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='C:Desktop/111/geckodriver.exe' , options=options)

driver.get(url)

time.sleep(3)

table = driver.find_element('id' , 'dgtopHolders')

print('--- headers ---')
row = table.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')[0]
for cell in row.find_elements_by_tag_name('th'):
    print(cell.text)

print('--- data ---')
for row in table.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')[1:]:
    for cell in row.find_elements_by_tag_name('td'):
        print(cell.text)
    print('---')
```

#Can you help me?
#thank you so much

Comment: Please check [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) You need to be specific: What exactly is your problem? A generic _Can you help me?_ isn't enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following method will get you the table as a pandas dataframe:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By    
import pandas as pd

[...]
driver.get(url)

table = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'dgtopHolders')))
dfs = pd.read_html(table.get_attribute('outerHTML'))
print(dfs[0])
```

Result:

```
Stock   Company Name    % of Portfolio  Shares  Value   % Change    Change  Ownership History   Price History   Date
0   CPNG    Coupang Inc Cl A    15.70%  19.43M  $ 343.60M   9.41%   1.67M   NaN NaN 2022-03-31
1   MSFT    Microsoft Corp  14.37%  1.02M   $ 314.57M   27.46%  219.81k NaN NaN 2022-03-31
2   FCX Freeport-mcmoran Inc Cl B   10.99%  4.84M   $ 240.58M   0%  0   NaN NaN 2022-03-31
3   AMZN    Amazon Com Inc  9.09%   1.22M   $ 198.85M   7.23%   82.30k  NaN NaN 2022-03-31
4   CVX Chevron Corp    7.18%   964.88k $ 157.11M   17.03%  140.44k NaN NaN 2022-03-31
5   TMUS    T-mobile Us Inc 5.23%   891.21k $ 114.39M   11.92%  94.90k  NaN NaN 2022-03-31
[...]
```

Comment: Hi! I am trying to create a datframe with scraping of different web page: this is the code. how can i resolve this problem ?

Comment: You just apply the code above to the new url.

Comment: I have more URL (approximately 40). Can I create a loop ?

Comment: I don't know if you can, but it's possible to create a loop, yes.